Cannot read unicode from stdin from regular PS and CMD windows
--test.lua
local s = io.read()
for i=1, utf8.len(s) do
    local cp = utf8.codepoint(s,i)
    print(cp)
    print(utf8.char(cp))
end

Run in a PowerShell terminal through the Terminal app:
C:\>chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001

C:\>lua test.lua
abæ
97
a
98
b
230
æ

C:\>

Notice the nonascii 'æ' gets printed and with it's codepoint value of 230
If I do the same from a regular PowerShell window (i.e. not through the Terminal app):
C:\>chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001

C:\>lua test.lua
abæ
97
a
98
b
0


C:\>

Now the 'æ' is not correctly interpreted.
I was debugging in VS Code and noticed this during of the sessions. At first I thought it was a problem with how VS Code ran the terminals, but it is apparently a more general difference between the regular PowerShell (and CMD) app and when it's run through the Terminal app. What gives?
Edit: As per JosefZ's request is here the output of ([console]::InputEncoding, [console]::OutputEncoding, $OutputEncoding) | Select-Object -Property EncodingName, WindowsCodePage, Codepage:
EncodingName      WindowsCodePage CodePage
------------      --------------- --------
Unicode (UTF-8)              1200    65001
OEM United States            1252      437
US-ASCII                     1252    20127

It's the same for both (PowerShell alone and PowerShell in Terminal)
I use Lua 5.4

AFAIK this is a bug in the WideCharToMultiByte API used by the Microsoft's terminal app. So other terminal apps that do not use this API won't have this issue.

My issue is the other way round. I don't see the issue in the terminal apps.

The terminal apps I'm referring are cmd.exe and powershell.exe

Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share (PowerShel) ([console]::InputEncoding, [console]::OutputEncoding, $OutputEncoding) | Select-Object -Property EncodingName, WindowsCodePage, Codepage
